# Focus commands doesn't work when auto executing thisworkbook events that was triggered while xlsx format?

Tags: excel, vba

When I close my workbook it triggers a BeforeClose Sub, which selects A1 in all sheets except one, which instead selects the most recent one.

For some reason, when it's another workbook that closes that workbook, activate commands is simply Ignored, the code runs the line... but doesn't change focus. which right after makes it select a out of bounds range, since it isn't the right sheet that is focused.

I have a "master" excel ark, which is used for several other excel sheets to automaticly open and run their code. the problem is that they are setup in a specific way so that if you close it runs a function (Workbook_BeforeClose) which selects A1 in all sheets except one called "Arkiv" which it selects the most recent row instead.

The problem rises since thisworkbook.activate and thisworkbook.sheets("arkiv").Activate is simply ignored if run by the event function if it was triggered aka. closed by another workbook code.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    If ThisWorkbook.Saved Then SaveStatus = vbYes Else SaveStatus = vbNo
    If SaveStatus = vbNo Then SaveStatus = MsgBox("Do you want to save before closing the workbook?", vbYesNoCancel, "Save Prompt")
    If SaveStatus = 2 Then Cancel = True: Exit Sub
    If SaveStatus = vbYes Then
    ThisWorkbook.Activate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each CloseSheet In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        CloseSheet.Activate 'activate it so it's selectable, and active
        Range("A1").Select
        RTS = 1 'Row To Scroll - Top if sheet is not Arkiv
        If CloseSheet.Name = "Arkiv" Then
            RTS = CloseSheet.Cells(2, 1).End(xlDown).Row
            CloseSheet.Cells(RTS, 2).Select 'ERROR HERE
            CloseSheet.Cells(RTS, 1).Select 'ERROR HERE
            RTS = RTS - 10
        End If
        ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = RTS 'Scroll to the top
        ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1 'Scroll to the left
    Next
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Select
    ThisWorkbook.Save
    End If
    ThisWorkbook.Saved = True
End Sub
```

I would expect the Workbook to be selected then each sheets to be selected one by one, but the focus doesn't change at all.

Comment: Do the other workbooks have screenupdating false or something in the lines? Try to enable screenupdating and debug with F8 line by line when your beforeclose triggers. Does the workbook comes to focus?

Comment: Try `RTS = CloseSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row`

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem and a somewhat solution...
I had completely missed to write this, but the workbook that triggers the event, is being saved as a .xlsx file before getting closed (as I can't save and close at the same time), which for some reason means changing the selection or focus via macros that still remain in the code module before closing, doesn't work.

My fix: I use "On Error Resume Next" before it in the event.
(ofc. with "on error goto 0" after the selections)
and make the reselecting part a seperate function, so I can call it externally before saving the macro.

Tough I wonder why temporary macroes can't change selections.